# Getting additional data associated with Axios.All requests down the line

Tags: typescript, axios

I have some code which gets a list of id's from a database, then using Axios.all gets information of each id from an external web-site. Some of the id's don't return the data I need from the external website (but I still get a 200).

In these instances I'd like to log something about that id in the database but by the time I get to that part of the code the id is not available to my code.

I have tried to illustrate this below.

```
interface ApiResponse {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const getAllRequests = async (ids: number[]) => {
  const requestBody = '....' // request body includes the id
  const requests = ids.map((id) => Axios.post<ApiResponse>('http://www.someurl.com', requestBody));
  return await Axios.all(requests);
};

const ids = [13123, 124214];

const doWork = async () => {
  const all = await getAllRequests(ids);

  all.forEach((x) => {
    if (x.name === undefined) {
      // how can I get the id associated with this request here, ideally
      // without looking in the request body
    }    
  });
};

doWork();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function passed to `forEach` can take a second argument, which is an array index. If you use `(x, i) => { ... }` instead of `(x) => { ... }`, then you can refer to `ids[i]` to find the corresponding ID.

Comment: Also don't use `Axios.all` as it is depreciated in favor of `Promise.all`...